# favicon: not shown in browser tab

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

The favicon is not shown at browser tab.

http://domain:8080/

```
<link rel="icon" href="/my-icon.png">
```

But can open the icon in browser.

```
http://domain:8080/my-icon.png
```

Comment: is the index HTML file in the same directory as `my-icon.png`?

Comment: Not every PNG file will work as a favicon. I usually use an online icon tool. The latest I have used, which is quite good, is: https://realfavicongenerator.net It will create all icons for you and include the HTML. But there are many others.

Comment: Ensure that the favicon image has the correct dimensions. For example, the standard size for a favicon is 16x16 pixels. If the image size is incorrect, it may not display correctly in the browser tab.

Comment: works for Edge.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the problem persists across different browsers - it is possible that your specific browser does not take this format.
2. Check that the link is placed in the proper location and the icon file exists in the corresponding directory
3. Try a different icon file format, e.g. .ico instead of .png

Good luck!

Comment: Works for Edge. What can be the issue for Chrome (a popular browser)?

Comment: Another site same code just works for Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't like your icon file. .ico file works for me in Chrome.

Comment: png works in another site for Chrome.  prefer png, and do not need conversion.